# Can I hide information from the device I use to encrypt it?

Tags: anonymity, electronic-voting

Assume I have some Information (i.e. my choice during an election) I want my device to encrypt. At the same time i don't want my device to know the meaning of the information it decrypts.

**Example**: Before voting I get a ballot and a coding card that indicates which choice represents which candidate. Now the Device can not know which candidate I voted, even if it knows what I "crossed".

**My Question:** Are there more such methods to hide the Information from my device?

Answer (score 3):

There are certain algorithms that allow you to do calculations on encrypted values. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption however the things are still slow and impractical.

What you can do in your example is create two 'machines'. When you insert a ballot in your apparatus, one machine independently counts votes (which hole you punched), the other independently keeps track of the randomizer on the ballot card. You can later then merge that data to count the vote in a third machine.

Machines here could be virtual or even separate scripts, depending on the degree of physical separation you need and how 'trusted' your code is. Independently the data sources do not mean anything to either machine, only when you put them together will it 'resolve'.